# Word Add In is inactive after installation?

Tags: c#, ms-word, installation, vsto, add-in

I have developed a word add-in solution. I have allso created a setup project and my installation files are working as they should (msi and exe).

But after the installation is my add-in inactive. I can change it to "active" in options and it works, just as it should, but this is not an option since we are installing it at many computers at once and the users does'nt know how to change this.

- It is an machine - installation for all users of the machine.
- Four registry keys, Description, FriendlyName, Manifest and most important LoadBehavior with the value of "3".
- Visual Studio 2015 Pro.
- The add - in is a word 2013 project and it is used for Office 2013

What am I missing? I thought LoadBehavior 3 would be enough for it to be active after installation but obviously am I missing something. Any ideas what it can be or if someone has any good idea how to get around this problem?

Thnx in advance

Comment: How are you installing the add-in, through a vsto? Is the package signed?

Comment: Yes it is a VSTO. But I have not signed anything extra. I have followed this guide, more or less, with some minor differences: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc442767.aspx Should it realy make any difference if I signed it? (Im all new to making installation files, normally not my job)

Comment: Does your application have a digital signature or a certificate ? In some cases when apps don't have a signed certificate they are put into the inactive addins category by default .

Comment: Did some changes with the certificate, followed a tutorial, I think it works now but will run it on some colleagues computers before I mark this as solved. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft Office applications can disable VSTO Add-ins that behave unexpectedly. If an application does not load your VSTO Add-in, the application might have hard disabled or soft disabled your VSTO Add-in.

Hard disabling can occur when an VSTO Add-in causes the application to close unexpectedly. It might also occur on your development computer if you stop the debugger while the Startup event handler in your VSTO Add-in is executing.

Soft disabling can occur when a VSTO Add-in produces an error that does not cause the application to unexpectedly close. For example, an application might soft disable a VSTO Add-in if it throws an unhandled exception while the Startup event handler is executing.

When you re-enable a soft-disabled VSTO Add-in, the application immediately attempts to load the VSTO Add-in. If the problem that initially caused the application to soft disable the VSTO Add-in has not been fixed, the application will soft disable the VSTO Add-in again. Read more about that in the [How to: Re-enable a VSTO Add-in That Has Been Disabled](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268871.aspx) article.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I managed to solve this with a signed certificate.